# Subscribing to ERC20(BEP20) events, in BSC

Tags: bsc

I am trying to setup a node to be able to query all BEP20 transactions in real time.

My `eth.syncing` stats are:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 9489998,
  highestBlock: 9490087,
  knownStates: 195328608,
  pulledStates: 195258505,
  startingBlock: 9487094
}
```

This is what I'm using

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 2, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {"topics": ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}]}
```

But I only get the following answer, and nothing more:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"result":"0x6760537a1d6add4f87899036f1826770"}
```

Anything I could be missing out?

Answer (score 1):

What you did was ask for a subscription, that won't give you anything other than an id to use to unsubscribe when you finish your work.

after subscribing, the node you are using will start sending you messages. if you are not constantly listening for them they simply won't show up. for this you will need to use a websocket provider.

if you are using python here how to do it :

```
import asyncio
import json

from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
import requests
from websockets import connect
from eth_abi import decode_single, decode_abi

adapter = requests.sessions.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=50000, pool_maxsize=50000)
session = requests.Session()
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider("<YOUR-WS-PROVIDER>"))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0) // this only for PoA chains like BSC



async def get_event():
    async with connect("ws://localhost:8545") as ws:
        await ws.send({"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 2, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {"topics": ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}]}
)
        subscription_response = await ws.recv()
        print(subscription_response)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                print(json.loads(message))
                pass
            except:
                pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(get_event())
```

Comment: Thanks! However, in the web socket client I should be able to see the messages I subscribed to. And that's what I don't see. There are no more messages, except for that first one I'm printing.

Comment: that means there are not messages for the topic you passed first, Also your node is still syncing and way off from the current state. so your topic might be none existent yet. try another provider, something like the open ones. @blasrodri

Comment: It's odd because sending the same message to a moralis node, gives me messages. Could it be that it's because the node is not yet synced?

Comment: Just don't use a not fully synced node.

Comment: What can I use instead?

Comment: @blasrodri use this : wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443 mainet bsc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127912/discussion-between-blasrodri-and-kaki-master-of-time).